# Online form with an input that is used in submit code

Tags: forms

I am trying to create an online form for my business that customers can sign and when they submit it, the job number that I manually typed will be taken and inserted into a code such as `[ESSM #"job number here" 0]` which will then link it by email. When I hit the submit button I want the email to send with that as the subject but haven't had much practice in web design other than HTML and CSS.

Comment: What languages do you have available to you to use?  A C# solution isn't going to work if you only have access to PHP, and vice versa.

Comment: Basically I will use what ever is easiest, I would be using dreamweaver or a program similar.